# Is there a way to find the span of a specific character followed by any number of a specific character?

Tags: python, python-re

Specifically I'm using this is in a discord bot but that doesn't (shouldn't) matter here. I'm currently using `re.search` to see if a character (say 'x') is present in a string and is followed by any number of a second character (say 'y') and return the span of it.

Current Code:

```py
if 'x' in message.content.lower(): # message.content is a string and is changed to all lowercase
    match = re.search('xyyy', message.content.lower()).span() # currently only finds 'x' followed by exactly three 'y's
    print(match) # prints the span of 'xyyy' as a tuple; such as (0,4)
    print(f'{message.content[match[0]:match[1]]}y') # prints the span of the message + 'y'
# both these print statements are 'await message.send()'s instead of prints
```

However the problem with this setup is that it only looks for x followed by exactly 3 ys. Am I just missing something obvious or is there a better module for this?

Comment: Do you mean `re.search(r'xy+', message.content.lower()).span()` ?

Comment: Wow, it really was just a single plus symbol. Thank you